# Bitmap with tile mode repeat and round corners

Tags: android, bitmap, rounded-corners, tile

I have a bitmap with rounded corners method:

Code:

```
 public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapDrawable TileMe = new BitmapDrawable(output);
    TileMe.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    TileMe.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(TileMe);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
        }
```

This is only making the image with rounded corners and also corners are not smooth, now how can i make it to tile with repeat mode along with rounded corners?

Answer (score 3):

Finally i have solved it !!!

```
class CurvedAndTiled extends Drawable {

    private final float mCornerRadius;
    private final RectF mRect = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mTilePaint;        

    CurvedAndTiled(
            Bitmap bitmap, 
            float cornerRadius) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        mTilePaint = new Paint();
        mTilePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTilePaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);             
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRect.set(0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mTilePaint);           
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mTilePaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mTilePaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }       
}
```

apply this too your image view.

```
backgroundImage.setBackgroundDrawable(new CurvedAndTiled(((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap(), 45));
```

Hope it will help someone in future.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out with extend `BitmapDrawable` and override the `paint()` method to set the image in tile mode:

*In this method we **avoid** creating a new bitmap having the size of the view.*

```
class MyBitmapDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    private boolean mRebuildShader = true;
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mRebuildShader) {
            mPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));
            mRebuildShader = false;
        }

        // Translate down by the remainder
        mMatrix.setTranslate(0, getBounds().bottom % getIntrinsicHeight());
        canvas.save();
        canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);
        canvas.drawRect(getBounds(), mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

It can be set to the view like this:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(new MyBitmapDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley).getBitmap()));
```

Check out its reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761184/android-drawing-tiled-bitmaps-with-bottom-or-some-other-alignments-similar-to-c)

Comment: But will this give me both the effect like rounded corners and tile mode repeat as well?

Comment: Do you want both the effects on image ? This will only give tile effect. You did not specify that you want both the effects?

Comment: thanks , but please see i have mentioned it as "Bitmap with tile mode repeat and round corners"

Comment: Check out similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311042/android-tile-bitmap/4575738#4575738